# Decoding Bluetooth signal and packets using GnuRadio

Tags: bluetooth, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am currently working on a project which aim to ***detect Bluetooth and decode Bluetooth*** ***packets*** (I use a **Hack RF One** to make the detection). I have made a Gnuradio Flowgraph in order to demodulate Bluetooth signal and I am trying to decode visualy the packets by searching a Bluetooth frame on a binary file.

Unfortunately, I didn't succeed to recover a clear view of the Bluetooth signal. To be precise, I am pretty sure that I detect Bluetooth on my sinks but when sending this to a **Clock Recovery + Binary Slicer** blocks, I am unable to recover interresting data in the binary file (especially the **MAC** adress of the sending device, which is part of the a Bluetooth packet). Moreover, I would like to know what type of network layer (physical, transport, baseband...) is intercepted in this type of process. In my case, I aim to intercept *baseband layer* packets.
Additionaly, I am interrested in knowing how to use the ***gr-bluetooth*** because I can't find a lot of documentation concerning this block. I think this can be interresting for the development of my project.

Could you please, give me your view, opinion about this problem ? I am stucked at this stage without knowing the exact origin of my issue. (Here is my flowgraph [GnuRadio_Flowgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxe4U.png) and a screenshot of one of my Bluetooth detection [Detected signal at 2.402GHz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY9NH.png)).

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an ubertooth instead https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10573
I read that the bluetooth frequency skipping is spread wider than the HackRF can read, so at-best, you're going to miss 75% of frames if you only have one hackrf connected.