# Bluetooth decoding using GNURadio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am working on developing blocks for Decoding and demodulating Bluetooth signal and then to show the sequence of 1s of 0s in demodulated signal.

I am trying to build blocks in GNURadio.

My question is : Is decoding Bluetooth previously built in GNU like photos or do we need to code it in python and build block by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is : Is decoding Bluetooth previously built in GNU like photos ...

Yes, [gr-bluetooth](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/gr-bluetooth) is an open source OOT(out of tree) module for gnuradio that implements bluetooth.

See also [Decoding Bluetooth signal and packets using GnuRadio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50208704/2315085)